# Exception in SolrJ after change in solrconfig.xml

Tags: java, solr, solrj

**SO**! This is my first question so be kind ;)

I've been working with Solr and I've found recently that it has <strike>almost</strike> not security at all..
So in a browser you can write 
`http://HOST:PORT/solr/update?stream.body=<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>&commit=true`
and delete my index in a breeze.

Reading the Solr wiki I edited my solrconfig.xml file, adding my own RequestHandler for updates.

```xml
<requestHandler name="/theupdate" 
   class="solr.XmlUpdateRequestHandler">
</requestHandler>
```

..instead of the default..

```xml
<requestHandler name="/update" 
   class="solr.XmlUpdateRequestHandler">
</requestHandler>
```

And now i'm getting this exception when adding a document collection to the server (before commit).

```
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: Server at http://HOST:PORT/solr returned non ok status:400, message:Missing solr core name in path
  at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:328)
  at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:211)
  at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:105)
  at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.add(SolrServer.java:69)
  at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.add(SolrServer.java:54)
```

This is my code for indexing:

```java
SolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer("http://HOST:PORT/solr");
Collection<SolrInputDocument> colection = new ArrayList<SolrInputDocument>();
SolrInputDocument solrDoc = new SolrInputDocument();
OracleCachedRowSet rsX = getDataFromDB(); // not actual line
while (rsX.next()) {
  solrDoc.addField("id", rsX.getLong(1), 1.0f);
  solrDoc.addField("name", rsX.getString(2), 1.0f);
  colection.add(solrDoc);
}
server.add(colection); //<-- the exception is thrown here!
server.commit();
colection.clear();
```

*Note: I read something about protecting Solr via firewall and/or basic authentication in the servlet container i'm working on that too...*

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been looking through the methods available on [HttpSolrServer](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-4_0_0-BETA/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpSolrServer.html) and the various `add` methods on [SolrServer](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-4_0_0-BETA/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrServer.html) in the SolrJ library and unfortunately, I do not see any place where you can override or specify a different name in SolrJ for the updateHandler. It assumes that it will be available via `http://HOST:PORT/solr/update`

Comment: that was fast!.. i think that if i cant workaround this, i'll have to take the firewall/auth aproach.. thanks!